# Не открывается клавиатура

Tags: python, aiogram

По нажатию кнопки "админ-панель" должна открываться админ-панель и появляться клавиатура снизу.

```
@router.callback_query(F.data.lower == "adminka")
async def add (callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.mesage.answer(text="Выберите действие",\
                                 reply_markup=admin_panel)
```

Comment: Сложно ответить не видя всего кода